# scala How to wait for several Futures

Tags: scala, future

I have seq

i want to do the iterate automatic

Comment: Not entirely on topic, but I strongly recommend scalaz tasks over futures. I've found futures have some weird behaviours, like IO being deferred to the end of execution.

Comment: Note: the OP deleted his/her question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `iterator` with `flatMap`. Here is a simplified example:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val functions: Seq[() => Future[Int]] = Seq(
  () => Future(1),
  () => Future(2),
  () => Future(3),
  () => Future(4),
  () => Future(5)
)

def checkResult(result: Int): Boolean = result > 3

functions.iterator.flatMap { func =>
  val result = Await.result(func(), 5.seconds)
  if (checkResult(result)) Some(result) else None
}.next()
```

This code would return *4*.

**Update:**

If you just care about the correct result and don't care whether or not all futures get executed, you could chain them with `fallBackTo`:

```
import scala.util._

functions.tail.foldLeft[Future[Int]](functions.head().filter(checkResult)) {
    case (result, function) =>
      result.fallbackTo(function().filter(checkResult))
}.onComplete {
  case Success(result) => s"Got one: $result"
  case Failure(exception) => s"Damn! Got NO result due to: $exception"
}
```

This would give you a `Future` that would complete with `Success(4)` with my example predicate `x > 3`.

**UPDATE 2**

As I found myself with some extra time, I took the liberty to combine some comments and suggestions in other answers (especially from [Alexander Azarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118613/alexander-azarov)) with a *loan pattern* approach:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val functions: Seq[() => Future[Int]] = Seq(
  () => Future(1),
  () => Future(2),
  () => Future(3),
  () => Future(4),
  () => Future(5)
)

def checkResult(result: Int): Boolean = result > 5

def withFirstValidResult[A, B](futureFuncs: Seq[() => Future[A]], predicate: A => Boolean, defaultValue: A)(op: (A) => B): Future[B] = {
  @tailrec
  @inline def find(remaining: Iterator[Future[A]]): Future[A] = {
    if (remaining.hasNext) {
      remaining.next().filter(predicate).recoverWith {
        case _ =>
        find(remaining)
      }
    } else {
      Future.successful {
        println(s"No valid result found, falling back to default: $defaultValue")
        defaultValue
      }
    }
  }


  find(futureFuncs.iterator.map(_())).map(op)
}
```

You can now use this function with any kind of futures you want and provide an operation that should be executed with the first valid result or the defaultValue (though IMHO in case of no valid result I'd prefer a `Failure` with proper error handling myself):

```
withFirstValidResult(functions.iterator, checkResult, 0) { result =>
  println(s"Got a valid result: $result")
}.onFailure {
  case ex =>
    println(s"Got NO valid result: $ex")
}
```

As an extra tip, if you want to speed up the function you can have the iterator lazily evaluate two functions at a time with `futureFuncs.iterator.buffered`. This way, while one future result is being evaluated, the iterator will automatically start the next future.

Comment: there is solution without to do Await?

Comment: Thanks!, any idea why i get  Future.filter predicate is not satisfied?

Comment: [NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not satisfied]]

Comment: @Ben.om That would happen if none of the results of your futures fulfill the predicate in `checkResult`. One would usually handle such a case in `onComplete` or `onFailure`. I'll edit my answer for an example.

Comment: I like your solution w/ `fold`

Answer (score 1):

```
def firstF[A](seq: Seq[() => Future[A]], predicate: A => Boolean): Future[A] =
  seq.head().filter(predicate).recoverWith {
    case _ => firstF[A](seq.tail, predicate)
  }
```

Method `firstF` will return the first `Future` that matches the condition specified. The resulting `Future` will be a `Failure` if none of the input `Future`s match. To return some default value otherwise, you would simply do

```
firstF(seq, predicate).recover { case _ => default }
```

---

**Note 1** the code here demonstrates basic principles and does not distinguish between planned or unplanned exceptions.

**Note 2** this code is not tail-recursive.

Comment: in this solution  i got NoSuchElementException: head of empty list

Comment: @Ben.om you'll get this exception if none of the elements matches the predicate. But you didn't specify this scenario in your question.

Comment: Ok, it can be if any function didn't much, so in this case i need to return defult value

Comment: It's the first time you mention "default" value. Please modify you question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f(x:String) = Future { x }

val functions = Seq(
  () => f("a"),
  () => f("b"),
  () => f(""),
  () => f("d"),
  () => f("e"))

functions.takeWhile( x => Await.result(x(), 5 seconds) != "")
```

This will give you

```
res0: Seq[() => scala.concurrent.Future[String]] = List(<function0>, <function0>)
```

Iam not sure if there is another approach but for my understanding if you want to decide based on the result of the preceeding future you need to wait.

**EDIT:**
Here is a recursive approach. But in my opinion the one with the iterator is good.

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def f(x:String) = Future { x }

val functions = Seq(
  () => f("a"),
  () => f("b"),
  () => f(""),
  () => f("d"),
  () => f("e"))


check(functions, 0)
def check(list:Seq[() => Future[String]], pos:Int):String = {
  if(list.size <= pos) return ""

  val res = Await.result(list(pos)(), 5 seconds)
  if(condition(res)) {
    res
  }
  else check(list, pos+1)
}

def condition(c:String):Boolean = if(c == "d") true else false
```

It's tail recursive therefore your stack won't overflow that easy.

Comment: there is solution without to do Await?

Comment: Not if you're depended on the previous result of the future. If you want to filter and drop each entry that is not matching your condition, then yes.

Comment: Ok,but in this solution when its finish i got the function and not the value

Comment: Look at my edit. I think thats another approach which will work. Otherwise use the one with the iterator.